# How to implement interprocess mutex in .NET Standard 2.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ipc, mutex, .net-standard

There is a [`Mutex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex) class in .NET Standard that can be named in order to support interprocess synchronization. However, it does not support setting [`MutexSecurity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.mutexsecurity) neither via constructor argument nor via [`SetAccessControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex.setaccesscontrol#applies-to).

When `MutexSecurity` is not applied, interprocess synchronization is not working on Windows.

Comment: Chicken-and-egg, it just isn't very "standard".  The concept is entirely missing in the unixes.  Ought to be only an issue when trying to interop with a service that's configured with a system account, that's not standard either.  Providing such details is pretty essential to get ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the explanation of constraints. Could you please provide it as an answer.

Comment: It is not an answer, I have but the foggiest idea why you need to solve this problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I am migrating a project to .NET Standard. There was a code with `MutexSecurity` that was required by some legacy cases/projects. I was trying to make this code compilable. I have found that `MutexSecurity` is supported in .NET Standard. After your explanation I've decided to remove the `MutexSecurity` for now. Legacy projects that would need `MutexSecurity` will be kept on .NET Framework version.